# I can only scroll using the left side of the screen

Tags: swift

When I was trying to make my scroll work, I did this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    collectionView?.bounces = true
    collectionView?.alwaysBounceVertical = true

    collectionView?.register(FriendCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
}
```

However, when I try to scroll, it only responds to the left half of the vertical screen, and not the middle or right side. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that the `collectionView` is covering the whole screen?

Comment: How would I check that?

Comment: This is my collectionview:

    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize.init(width: view.frame.size.width, height: 100)
    }

Comment: Thats the size of one cell, try `print(collectionView?.frame)` and see what is printed